# Neo4j/Cypher - find nodes that only link to given parents

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to come up with a cypher query that can return child nodes of certain parents where both parents of the children are amongst the desired parents.

I've got an example dataset at this console: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=nsq8c1

In the example we have group nodes which contain parent nodes, and child nodes that have exactly 2 parents, and all parents across all groups have a child with every other parent. Now I want to get back the children that have both of their parents in group1.

The example query I try is `match (group { name: "group1" })-[:contains]->(parent)-[:has_child]->(child) return child`, which just returns all children, instead of just childofsamandjane.

Given group1, how do you get just childofsamandjane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sbs,

Here's one way to do it:

```
MATCH (group { name: "group1" })-[:contains]->(parent)-[:has_child]->(child)
WITH group, parent, child
MATCH (child)<-[:has_child]-(parent2)<-[:contains]-(group)
WHERE parent <> parent2
RETURN DISTINCT child
```

You match from parents in the group to all of their children, then from each child back to a different parent in the same group.

Grace and peace,

Jim